# How to have more than one version of Protractor and switch between them?

Tags: protractor

Is there any way to have more than one version, or revert to an old 
version?

thankful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's a catch though.

You can only do that only in different versions of `node` & `npm` using `nvm - node version manager` .

Install one version of protractor in one version of node and other version in another version of node. Now if you want to switch between different versions of protractor you need to switch the node version using `nvm`.

- [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.markdown)
- [protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/)

Comment: Is there a way to make this switch on the node with the protractor in the same version of the node?

Comment: Apparently its a no for a same version of node on same machine, no npm package can run with multiple versions on same version of node with both installed at same instant. This is obvious intuitionally . You can instead install and uninstall versions according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to install a specific version of protractor by using the command `npm install -g protractor@version-number`.

you can find the list of available versions from [protractor versions](https://github.com/angular/protractor/releases)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have node installed uninstall and remove all associated folders.
2. Download and install 'nvm' as administrator user from https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows, install instructions will be available in the same page.
3. Once it is installed, you can install the node versions using

   `nvm install nodeVersionYouWant`
4. Then you can install protractor for the supported node version like

   `npm install -g protractor@<version>  //-g for global installation`
5. Once you installed your node and protractor versions, you can switch and run the nodes of different version in different command terminals using command

   `nvm use <nodeVersion>`
6. So if you need to run the protractor for that particular version, just type

   `protractor <testFile>  //This would run in the protractor version you have installed for that particular node version`

I hope this would solve your need. You can run as many versions as you want till your system memory permits.